# Swift Class Variable Crashing Interface Builder Live Rendering

Tags: ios, swift, rendering

In Swift I've made a custom view by subclassing UIView:

```
@IBDesignable class HandView: UIView {

var view:UIView!
var settings:AppSettings?

@IBOutlet weak var c1ImageView: UIImageView!
@IBInspectable var c1Image:UIImage? { didSet { self.c1ImageView?.image = self.c1Image } }

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //self.settings = AppSettings.sharedInstance
    self.xibSetup()
  }
}
```

When I add this view to my storyboard, Live Rendering works as expected.  As soon as I uncomment the line:

```
//self.settings = AppSettings.sharedInstance
```

Live Rendering crashes - I get the following error messages:

```
error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of BetView: Rendering the view took 
error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of HandView: The designables agent 
crashed
```

The app compiles and runs as it should.  The only thing impacted is Live Rendering.  The AppSettings class is a singleton:

```
class AppSettings {

//This makes AppSettings a singleton
class var sharedInstance: AppSettings {
    struct Static {
        static let instance: AppSettings = AppSettings()
    }
    return Static.instance
}

private let settings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

init () {
    //Load default values from the plist file
    let settingsBundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Defaults", ofType: "plist")
    let settingsDefaults = NSDictionary (contentsOfFile: settingsBundleURL!)
    self.settings.registerDefaults(settingsDefaults!)
}
```

I'm not sure why it's choking or what to do about it.  I don't want to stop using Live Rendering, because it's been very useful for developing my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override **init(frame: CGRect)** in your HandView

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.settings = AppSettings.sharedInstance
        self.xibSetup()
}
```

And also fix AppSettings class. This line of code from AppSettings init() method

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Defaults", ofType: "plist")
```

returns optional value. So you need to use optional binding to find out whether settingsBundleURL contains value before using it.

```
 init () {
    //Load default values from the plist file
    let settingsBundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Defaults", ofType: "plist")
    if let url = settingsBundleURL {
       let settingsDefaults = NSDictionary (contentsOfFile: settingsBundleURL!)
       self.settings.registerDefaults(settingsDefaults!)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Added init(frame: CGRect) as above and also required init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) but problem persists.